# How to find differences between two dates in textbox?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

i want to find find differences between two dates, where m giving date value in the text box and i want the differences/duration  to some  other textbox.

```
 <script language=javascript>
        function formshowhide(id) {
      if (id == "other") {
          //document.getElementById('quotef').style.display = "block";
          document.getElementById('otherf').style.display = "block";

     //here m writng the function for finding duration
          var txtdate1 = document.getElementById('MainContent_txtOStartDate').value;
          var txtdate2 = document.getElementById('MainContent_txtOEndDate').value;
          var date1 = new Date(txtdate1.split('-')[0], txtdate1.split('-')[1] - 1, txtdate1.split('-')[2]);
          var date2 = new Date(txtdate2.split('-')[0], txtdate2.split('-')[1] - 1, txtdate2.split('-')[2]);
          var timediffsec = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();
          var timediffday = parseInt(timediffsec / (24 * 3600 * 1000));
          document.getElementById('MainContent_txtDays').value = timediffday;
     //here the function end for finding the duration
      }
      else {
          // document.getElementById('quotef').style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById('otherf').style.display = "none";
      }
  }
  </script>
```

Comment: You don't need the c# and asp.net tags if you are requiring a javascript answer :-)

Comment: You want to convert the posted code into aspx?

Comment: i wnt this script to wrk with aspx code...

Comment: Posted code looks to be working to me, but I can't see the input, which might be the source of your problem.

Have you tried debugging with Firebug (or similar)? This coud tell you more precisely where the code goes bang.

Comment: You want the script to work with aspx code? Please explain...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Assuming you already have validation on the date input text boxes
DateTime startDate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtOStartDate.Text);
DateTime endDate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtOEndDate.Text);
TimeSpan timeDiff = startDate - endDate;
```

Then you can display whatever you want from the timespan:

```
string.Format("{0} days, {1} hours and {2} minutes.", timeDiff.Days, timeDiff.Hours, timeDiff.Minutes);
```